# Is there a jQuery library that can fit images to a div in a collage-like format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm specifically looking at http://500px.com/flow, something I want to mimic on my portfolio.

I would like to have my images go the full width, 1/4 or 1/2 width of the div and fade in. They would organize themselves in a newspaper or magazine-like format. I'll program this myself if I have to, but hoping to use a library I can hack.

Here's the only one I've found so far:
http://boedesign.com/demos/jsquares/

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Comment: I wasn't asking for a recommendation, I was asking if one exists.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree. You already found one, and linked to it.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/index4.html or http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/DraggableImageBoxesGrid/.  But I'm not posting this as an "answer" per @MДΓΓБДLL's input.

Comment: Program it yourself. Put your image's in object/array and use jQuery to iterate and insert them into separate divs accordingly. Since your using JavaScript, I am assuming your images are being fed from a server. You should elaborate more on the specifics of your data. Where are the images located?... are you just getting the link addresses?, if so what format? json, xml, what?... etc.. etc...

Comment: This feels like Wikipedia all over again. Thanks @Marc. I'll try and be more specific next time @ cube.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin which helps to display images as a collage directly - https://github.com/sandeepravi/collage.

Comment: It's a nice plugin with properly explained